# Fetch user from database after authentication with OneloginSamlBundle

Tags: symfony, onelogin

My Symfony (4.4) app uses the [OneloginSamlBundle](https://github.com/hslavich/OneloginSamlBundle) bundle to authenticate users against a SAML identity provider. This works fine. I receive the SAML response and the User Provider instantiates my `User` class correctly. However, I want that once I get the authentication SAML response, the corresponding user is instead fetched from my database. How could I do this ?

I guess I need to create a [custom user provider](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#creating-a-custom-user-provider) which would use the OneloginSamlBundle userprovider AND then fetch the user, but I don't know how I am supposed to do it with Symfony.

Comment: do you need the user in a controller? If so, just inject (or fetch from container - you didn't specified symfony version) `UserProviderInterface` and you should be good.

Comment: Added Symfony version, thanks. Your solution would work but I think this is something that should happen earlier, in the security layer. I could need the `User` objet before the controller (e.g. `kernel.request` event)

Comment: as long as user is authenticated, you can retrieve it from `UserProvider`

Comment: Please can you provide the settings of your saml.yaml, security.yaml and your User-Entity. I got a running solution build on top of Symfony 5 and OneloginSamlBundle 2.1.2.